# Laravel multiple post request same url

Tags: php, laravel

What's the best way of handling two different post request on the same url in Laravel? Should I use jobs or what's the normal way of doing this?

Already looked at some articles like this one:

[handle multiple post requests to same url Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279329/handle-multiple-post-requests-to-same-url-laravel-5)

But is that the right way of doing this?

Comment: Try out what has been suggested in the link that you have posted and if you face any problem with that, come back and ask a clear question.

Comment: @MadhavDatt why is that relevant to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the article you provided should work, why don't you try this https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use guzzle http for multiple get or post request using php
https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/http